# How to get HTML form data for user Object | Spring Boot | Controller |

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to create a simple Web application to register user. I am facing a  problem that I can't get the data from the HTML form in my controller method. I have tried a lot of stuffs but gone in vain

**Main class:**

```html
package main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class Web1Application {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(Web1Application.class, args);
 }
}
```

Here is my controller class:

**Controller class**

```html
package main.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import main.models.Test;

@Component
@Controller
public class WebController {

 @RequestMapping("/register")
 public ModelAndView getRegistrationPage() {
  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
  mv.setViewName("register.jsp");
  return mv;
 }
  
 @RequestMapping("/saveuser")
 public void handle(Test user) {
  System.out.println(user);
 }
}
```

Here is my Test class I was using some other class but is was testing so ..

**Entity class**

```html
package main.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Entity
public class Test {

 @Id
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private String username;
 private String password;
  //getters + setters + toString  
}
```

Here is my html form tag. I am using this code in jasper file.

**register HTML file**

```html
<form action="/saveuser" method="post">
  
  <label for="id">Name: </label>
  <input type="number" name="id">
  
  <label for="name">Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  
  <label for="username">User Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="username">
  
  <label for="password">Password: </label>
  <input type="password" name="password">
  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**POM dependencies**

```html
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
   <version>9.0.35</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

**Eclipse IDE console log**

```html
2020-06-03 12:15:46.301  INFO 8260 --- [           main] main.Web1Application                     : Starting Web1Application on DESKTOP-1FI2H1T with PID 8260 (C:\Users\Pancham Goyal\git\Web-Repository\Web-1\target\classes started by Pancham Goyal in C:\Users\Pancham Goyal\git\Web-Repository\Web-1)
2020-06-03 12:15:46.306  INFO 8260 --- [           main] main.Web1Application                     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-03 12:15:47.455  INFO 8260 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-06-03 12:15:47.555  INFO 8260 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 87ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-06-03 12:15:48.376  INFO 8260 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-06-03 12:15:48.389  INFO 8260 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-03 12:15:48.389  INFO 8260 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-06-03 12:15:48.801  INFO 8260 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-06-03 12:15:48.807  INFO 8260 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-03 12:15:48.808  INFO 8260 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2436 ms
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2020-06-03 12:15:49.152  INFO 8260 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-03 12:15:49.214  INFO 8260 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-06-03 12:15:49.261  WARN 8260 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-06-03 12:15:49.302  INFO 8260 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-06-03 12:15:49.538  INFO 8260 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-06-03 12:15:49.547  INFO 8260 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7f92b990, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2f1ea80d, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@34cf294c, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@4f4c789f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@c808207, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@778db7c5, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@f1a45f8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1ffcf674, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@31e04b13, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@604b1e1d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@21618fa7, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@7a8136b3]
2020-06-03 12:15:49.840  INFO 8260 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-06-03 12:15:49.841  WARN 8260 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2020-06-03 12:15:50.030  INFO 8260 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-06-03 12:15:50.049  INFO 8260 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2020-06-03 12:15:51.001  INFO 8260 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-06-03 12:15:51.013  INFO 8260 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-03 12:15:51.815  INFO 8260 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-06-03 12:15:51.817  INFO 8260 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-06-03 12:15:51.917  INFO 8260 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-06-03 12:15:51.932  INFO 8260 --- [           main] main.Web1Application                     : Started Web1Application in 6.27 seconds (JVM running for 8.203)
```

After submitting form on page i get this white label error on screen
**Error After submit press**

Error on chrome After submit press
[image]

file pattern
[image]

**Thank You :)**

Comment: Can you add some information (what works, what doesn't), e.g. does your application starts properly (is there any hint in the log file that some component didn't initialize?), are you able to receive requests, does the browser debug network tab tell you if the request was sent and what the response was?

Comment: when you try to run register request, share the information, or error responses you see in your browser's network tab and your server logs. If you are running from IDE then console logs.

Comment: @DirkR well i didn't received any exception in console box i received two warnings which were related to my jdbc and Jpa repository nothing else

Everything works fine it's just issue in registering process like my entered data in form i can't receive it in my controller class

Comment: @MuneebMirza i am receiving forbidden error on chrome ... Is it spring security? i have that too enabled

Comment: Can you share that error? that is an important information to debug the issue. Forbidden means there are issues with your request and what server is expecting. Check Html Error Codes, and you may understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use POST on the controller that's why I was getting this error and there were many other mistakes. Thanks!